# Use Min Max in C++ for more than 4 variables without using array

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

I'm new to C++ for a few days. I have an assignment about Min/Max and i have to find min and max of 4 variables without using array. Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: make one variable that is the min/max of the first two and another that is the min/max of the second two and then a third that is the min/max of those two calculated variables.

Comment: Are all 4 variables of the same type?

Comment: It is very likely that the solutions below do not satisfy a teacher, except if the purpose of the assignment is to teach about using standard mechanisms - which somehow I doubt, because September is not that long ago.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the header of the question and its content. Do you have exactly 4 variables or you are asking about "more than 4" as it's stated in the header?

Comment: This, as most questions which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump, is too broad to be answered. It lacks the required demonstration of some own effort. To fix that, have a look here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions If you do your part of the compromise described there, it will solve the problem with your question I described.

Comment: Duc Nguyen, also have a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Especially the part starting with "Post the question and respond to feedback". People here can get annoyed by the impression "Here is my homework, I will pick up the solution tomorrow, see you then."

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 the standard algorithms of [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and `std::max` can take an initializer list. So simply pass all 4 variables.

```
#include <algorithm>

auto low = std::min( {v1, v2, v3, v4} );
auto high = std::max( {v1, v2, v3, v4} );
```

(Or do it in one statement with [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax))

Answer (score 1):

You can use this notation by using initializer_list if you can use C++11.

> std::min({var1, var2, var3, var4});

This notation also can realize almost same function without c++11 environment.

> std::min( std::min(var1, var2), std::min(var3, var4) );

std::max also same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions to find out minimum and maximum as per your requirement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d , max, min;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> d;

    if ( a > b && a > c && a > d) {
        max = a;
    }
    else if (b > a && b > c && b > d) {
        max = b;
    }
    else if (c > a && c > b && c > d) {
        max = c;
    }
    else if (d > a && d > b && d > c) {
        max = d;
    }
    if (a < b && a < c && a < d) {
        min = a;
    }
    else if (b < a && b < c && b < d) {
        max = b;
    }
    else if (c < a && c < b && c < d) {
        min = c;
    }
    else if (d < a && d < b && d < c) {
        min = d;
    }

    cout << "Maximum is " << max<<endl;
    cout << "Minimum is " << min;

}
```

For finding minimum and maximum of numbers, 
you can use use conditions where you can compare each variable with other.  like if first number "a" is greater than second number "b",  also  first number "a" is greater than third number "c" and also first number "a" is greater than fourth number "d" Hence first number "a" is your maximum number. If this condition fails than you should have to compare other numbers. 
Same for finding minimum. Hope this explanation helps

Comment: This code is very convoluted. And entering 4 times the first number is also somewhat strange (hello careless copy/paste).

Comment: As "improveable" as this is (four times "first", really...), it might be the only answer which passes a teachers "does it seem copied from StackOverflow" check, if they do not actually come here. The other answers are a bit off for a "programming 101 class".

Comment: @Jabberwocky You are right about the four "first". But convoluted? Come one, I have rarely seen a more straight-forward piece of code. Maybe too straight, but not convoluted.

Comment: @Yunnosch OK, convoluted is maybe not the best term, but it's naive and error prone.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Half with you there again. Apart from the input problems, which are usually ignored in this context (optimistically assuming correct input), you could elaborate the error vulnerabilities you are thinking of, to get me fully on your side.

Comment: @Yunnosch with so many ifs and else ifs and conditions you can easily have a typo such as `c < a` instead of `c < b` which could go unnoticed especially if there are no extensive tests. It's not clear to me at first sight if all cases are actually covered.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Point accepted. I really agree. This kind of "maintainability" and "robustness" (very important things in my professional life) is however a little beyond an obvious audience of a "beginner programming" class. Still, I am with you to teach those things early. So, yes. I am fully with you now.